Quarkus Panache find null column in a query
I'm using Panache for querying a DB table where I can have null values in some columns.
I want to find a row searching for 2 column.
I'm using this syntax but not works for null values
Entity.find("column1 = ?1 and column2= ?2", value1, value2);

Searching on the web, I found this solution but it is too verbose:
if (address != null) {
    query.append(" and address = :address");
    params.put("address", address);
} else {
    query.append(" and address is null");
}

Entity.list(query.toString(), params);

Are any shorter ways to do this?

use coalesce(address,'') = ''
